# Grails 2.3.8 check url mappings for string occurence

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, url-mapping

I am trying to map the following

> //localhost:8080/user/login/&debug=1

...

> //localhost:8080/user/&debug=1

If there is any occurrence of string '&debug=1' then execute some-controller's action.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a URLMapping like this

```
"/**&debug=1"(controller:"defaultDebug"){
    action = [GET: "show"]
}
```

By using the double wildcard you can catch anything that ends with `&debug=1`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [**filter**](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Plug-ins/filters.html) to do the redirect when required.

```
class DebugFilters {
    def filters = {
        debugCheck(controller: '*', action: '*') {
            before = {
                if (params.debug == '1') {
                    redirect(controller: 'some', action: 'debug')
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to just switch between controllers and actions for a particular url mapping then you can also use a url mapping as below, instead of the filter altogether:

```
//UrlMappings.groovy
"/user/login" {
    controller = { params.debug == '1' ? 'some' : 'user' }
    action     = { params.debug == '1' ? 'debug': 'index' }

    // Note the use of a closure in ternary operations
    // params is available in a closure (delegated) 
    // because it is not available in by default
}
```